# What's the difference between these two XPath expressions?

Tags: javascript, html, xpath

There are two XPath expressions:

```
//LI/A[normalize-space()="fullscreen"]
//LI/A["fullscreen"]
```

As I understand, `normalize-space()` is used to trim strings, as said in [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/normalize-space). So the two expressions should have the same meaning?

But the first one can be evaluated to locate the element in [this web page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/evaluate) by:

```
document.evaluate('//LI/A[normalize-space()="fullscreen"]', document).iterateNext();
```

, while the second will locate a different element.

What's the difference between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second expression does not actually make much sense. The only condition you set to filter `a` elements is the "fullscreen" string, which will always evaluate to true. In other words, `//LI/A["fullscreen"]` is equivalent to `//LI/A`.

You probably meant to check the element's string value against `fullscreen`:

```
//LI/A[. = "fullscreen"]
```

It is also important to note that when `normalize-space()` is called with no arguments, it will automatically *use the string value of the current node as an argument*. The node's string value for an element is [all text nodes within the element concatenated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5992350/771848).

Comment: As I understand, `normalize-space()="fullscreen"` means call `normalize-space()` on `"fullscreen"`, and put the return value into `[]`. Correct? If not, what does it mean?

Comment: @MartinZhai I've added some more information into the answer, hope it makes things a little bit clearer. Thanks.