# Python selenium issue when using contains text with a span element

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver

I'm trying to grab a span element that has text " collections". I attach a screenshot of the HTML code.
I need to get this element not using the class values but just the text.
This is what I tried without any luck.
Notice that there's an empty space before the word 'colelctions/'

```
//*[contains(text(),' collections')]
```

It seems a pretty simple thing to do but somehow it doesn't work.
Any suggestions?
Many thanks[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use below instead:

```
//*[contains(.,' collections')]
```

or

```
//*[contains(text()[2],' collections')]
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5992177/what-is-the-difference-between-normalize-space-and-normalize-spacetext) is a post about difference between `.` and `text()`

Comment: thank you, the first option works. May I ask how come my solution above doesn't work? What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: I guess this is because `//*[contains(text(),' collections')]` is trying to evaluate the text of the first text node. Note that `span` node contains 2 child text nodes and the first one is just a space/new line character...

Comment: you're totally right. I recently found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9493732/difference-between-text-and-string and key take away was the presence of empty spaces in the string value that was probably not causing my code to work. Thank you so much for your answers, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To grab the element with text as **collections** as the element is an [Angular](https://angular.io/) element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* and you can use the following solution:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[normalize-space()='collections']")
```

Comment: thank you. Please, one quick question. How can you tell from the code it's angular element?