# Scrapy 'normalize-space()' is truncating the whole string

Tags: python, scrapy

I am scraping an XML document like this:

```
>>> response.xpath("//ul[@class='meta-info d-flex flex-wrap align-items-center list-unstyled justify-content-around']/li[position()=2]/text()").extract()
```

and is giving me the following output:

```
['\n            ', '\n\t\t\t                ', '\n\t\t\t\t24 Feb, 2019        ', '\n            ', '\n\t\t\t                ', '\n\t\t\t\t24 Feb, 2019        ', '\n            ', '\n\t\t\t                ', '\n\t\t\t\t24 Feb, 2019        ', '\n            ', '\n\t\t\t                ', '\n\t\t\t\t24 Feb, 2019        ', '\n            ', '\n\t\t\t                ', '\n\t\t\t\t24 Feb, 2019        ', '\n            ', '\n\t\t\t                ', '\n\t\t\t\t24 Feb, 2019        ', '\n            ', '\n\t\t\t                ', '\n\t\t\t\t24 Feb, 2019        ', '\n            ', '\n\t\t\t                ', '\n\t\t\t\t24 Feb, 2019        ', '\n            ', '\n\t\t\t                ', '\n\t\t\t\t24 Feb, 2019        ', '\n            ', '\n\t\t\t                ', '\n\t\t\t\t24 Feb, 2019        ', '\n            ', '\n\t\t\t                ', '\n\t\t\t\t24 Feb, 2019        ', '\n            ', '\n\t\t\t                ', '\n\t\t\t\t24 Feb, 2019        ', '\n            ', '\n\t\t\t                ', '\n\t\t\t\t24 Feb, 2019        ', '\n            ', '\n\t\t\t                ', '\n\t\t\t\t23 Feb, 2019        ', '\n            ', '\n\t\t\t                ', '\n\t\t\t\t24 Feb, 2019        ', '\n            ', '\n\t\t\t                ', '\n\t\t\t\t24 Feb, 2019        ', '\n            ', '\n\t\t\t                ', '\n\t\t\t\t24 Feb, 2019        ', '\n            ', '\n\t\t\t                ', '\n\t\t\t\t24 Feb, 2019        ', '\n            ', '\n\t\t\t                ', '\n\t\t\t\t24 Feb, 2019        ', '\n            ', '\n\t\t\t                ', '\n\t\t\t\t24 Feb, 2019        ', '\n            ', '\n\t\t\t                ', '\n\t\t\t\t24 Feb, 2019        ']
```

But I do not want any fields that are either newlines, tabs or whitespaces, so I am trying to use the `normalize-space()` function, as follows:

```
>>> response.xpath("normalize-space(//ul[@class='meta-info d-flex flex-wrap align-items-center list-unstyled justify-content-around']/li[position()=2]/text())").extract()
```

But I am getting a null output:

```
['']
```

What is happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used regex to solve a similar problem, which I included below, if you want to test it. I found that it works well. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5992177/what-is-the-difference-between-normalize-space-and-normalize-spacetext) should answer what is happening with normalize-space. It's expected to return an empty string on a text node.

```
import re
item_text = response.xpath("//ul[@class='meta-info d-flex flex-wrap align-items-center list-unstyled justify-content-around']/li[position()=2]/text()").extract()
re.sub('[\s]{2,}', '\n', "".join(item_text).strip())
```

Comment: Just FYI, `[\s]{2,}` is `\s{2,}`, the character class is unnecessary. But you always should use a raw string for regex `r'\s{2,}'`.

Comment: Thanks, I did know about raw strings, it's not something I've always applied, but will from now on.

Answer (score 1):

`normalize-space()` works on *a single string.* You are giving it a whole list of nodes.

So it takes the first one, converts that to string, and returns the result. Your first node has a value of `'\n            '`.

Write a `for` loop over `//ul[@class='meta-info d-flex flex-wrap align-items-center list-unstyled justify-content-around']/li[position()=2]` and call `normalize-string()` on the individual nodes.