# Why does normalize-space(text()) not work with a preceding child element?

Tags: html, xpath

No doubt that this is extremely basic, but it just won't "click" for me, despite the research that I've done so far. Given the following two HTML examples:

**Example 1**

```
<div _ngcontent-c35="" class="row facet-container ng-star-inserted">
    <div _ngcontent-c35="" class="searchresult-header">
        Locatie
    </div>
</div>
```

**Example 2**

```
<div _ngcontent-c42="" class="row facet-panel ng-star-inserted">
    <div _ngcontent-c42="" class="facet-panel-header brand-pointer" data-target="#ft5" data-toggle="collapse">
        <span _ngcontent-c42="" class="icon-plus ng-star-inserted" data-target="#ft5" data-toggle="collapse">
        </span> 
        Locatie
    </div>
    <div _ngcontent-c42="" class="collapse" id="ft5">
    </div>
</div>
```

Now I have the following piece of xpath:

*//div[.//div[normalize-space(text())='Locatie']]*

According to other [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5992350/1099834) and websites about xpath, text() selects text nodes directly descending from the node we're searching on. Therefore, in example #1, I expect to retrieve the first child "div" element. This happens correctly: no issues there.

I expect the same result in example #2. However, this is not the case: apparently the "span" element disrupts this specific search. When I manually remove it, I succesfully retrieve the required "div" element. Why is the search disrupted? The text should still be a direct child of the div element, no matter if the span element is there or not.

**TLDR: Why does the "span" element prevent me from finding the second "div" element in example #2?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [Jason had answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55695265/11102282) this is because the signature of [`normalize-space()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-normalize-space) function, from the specs:

> **Function**: *string* **normalize-space**(*string*?)

In XPath 1.0, whenever a string argument is needed, the language applies a type conversion by means of the [`string()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-string) function. From the specs:

> A node-set is converted to a string by returning the string-value of
>   the node in the node-set that is first in document order. If the
>   node-set is empty, an empty string is returned.

So, the resulting node-set from the `text()` node test is reduced to the **first node in document order** and then that node is converted to its [string-value](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#dt-string-value).

In this regards is when the always oversees whitespace only text nodes come to notice: your `div` element has two text nodes:

```
<div>
    <div>
        <!-- HERE ENDS THE FIRST --><span>
        </span> 
        Locatie
    <!-- HERE ENDS THE SECOND --></div>
    <div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Whenever you have mixed content markup, it's better to use the string-value rather than the text nodes.** Otherwise you should use this expression:

```
//div[.//div/text()[normalize-space()='Locatie']]
```

Comment: Plus 1 for mentioning mixed content.

Answer (score 2):

I guess that's because `normalize-space(text())='Locatie']` intend to check the *first* child text node (which is actually just an empty string) while you need to check the *second* one:

```
//div[.//div[normalize-space(text()[2])='Locatie']]
```

If you need generic XPath that will work for both cases try

```
//div[normalize-space(div)='Locatie']
```

Answer (score 0):

It may have something to do do with the white text/spaces (it's way over my pay grade...), because with this change of focus, the following expression seems to work with most (not all) xpath testers:

```
.//div[text()[contains(.,'Locat')]]
```