# What is the meaning of " . " in contains method in selenium xpath

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

Here what is the meaning of "." in the given xpath:

```
//a[contains(.,'Java SE 8')]
```

Comment: In regex, the period ( . ) is a wildcard that matches any character except newline.

Comment: @c_sagan: Regex syntax doesn't apply in this context.

Answer (score 0):

The . is similar to the `text()` attribute, but the . does not handle a case where another child element appears inside the element with the text "Java SE 8".

This thread explains in much more detail: [XPath: difference between dot and text()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38240763/xpath-difference-between-dot-and-text)

Comment: does it also work for "normalize-space( )" ?

Comment: Yes, you can use normalize-space(), the same concept applies. There's a good explanation about that here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5992177/what-is-the-difference-between-normalize-space-and-normalize-spacetext